# How to set default date in Materialize Date Picker?

Tags: datepicker, materialize

I need to set default date to `now` in a [Materialize Date Picker](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html).

```
<input id="since" type="text" class="datepicker">

<script>
    $("#since").datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy/mm/dd 00:00:00',
        defaultDate: 'now', // It doesn't work.
     // defaultDate: '2021/09/09 00:00:00', // It neither work.
        setDefaultDate: true
    
    });
<script>
```

Comment: It says it accepts `Date` object

Comment: JavaScript Date object?

Comment: Yes, a Javascript Date object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker">

<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const now = new Date();
    const nextDate = new Date(now);
    nextDate.setDate(now.getDate() + 1)
    
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
    var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, {
      defaultDate: nextDate,
      setDefaultDate: true,
    });
  });
</script>
```

The document says that in order to change the default date value then use 2 properties - **defaultDate** and **setDefaultDate**. I used the options in vanilla js but the same options can work with jQuery also.

Working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/germavinsmoke/pen/YzQYmbr)